# Universality of Quantum Operations

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer

Does an analog of the Solovay-Kitaev theorem exist for quantum operations, a generalization of quantum gates that also includes all completely positive maps?

Comment: To me, "quantum operations" refers to general completely positive maps. In this setting, I don't know of any such result, which doesn't mean it doesn't exist. If you don't want the full generality of completely positive maps, you should specify

Comment: Yes, I am referring to completely positive maps. Thank you for clarifying, will edit.